# Start animation that begins with current value (handoff).

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard, datatrigger

I have a WPF Datatemplate that contains a some **DataTriggers** that start animating the color of a visual. How can I start the animation beginning with the actual value the color property currently has?

Since there might be another animation currently active I can not start a new one but when I remove the animation using **DataTriggers** ExitAction and RemoveStoryboard the position property is set back to its default value.

Instead I would like handoff one to the other.

Is this a limitation of WPF that simply can not be done?

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="Active">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="activeStoryboard" HandoffBehavior="SnapshotAndReplace">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation To="Green" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Duration="00:00:0.25" 
                                Storyboard.TargetName="stateBrush" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="activeStoryboard" />
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="Error">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="errorStoryboard" HandoffBehavior="SnapshotAndReplace">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation To="Red" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Duration="00:00:0.25" 
                                Storyboard.TargetName="stateBrush" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="errorStoryboard" />
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: I would be really interested in a solution to this. Did you find out how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It should just work if you start the second animation, even if FillBehavior is set to Stop!

Check the following section on msdn: [FillBehavior="Stop" and HandoffBehavior with Multiple Animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613592.aspx)

Comment: THANK YOU! Been trying to animate an ellipse rotation and have it "snap" back to angle 0 when the trigger exits. Answer was to pause the prior storyboard and just spin a new one without a `From` property!